# How do I see the methods associated with an object in Clojure?

Tags: java, methods, clojure

What function do I use, in Clojure, to see the methods of a Java object?

```
user=> (some-function some-java-object)
... lots of methods ...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use java reflection.

```
(.getClass myObject)
```

gets you the class.  To get methods,

```
(.getMethods (.getClass myObject))
```

Which gives you an array of methods.  You can treat that like a sequence;  I'd probably put it into a vector, so:

```
(vec (.getMethods (.getClass myObject)))
```

Answer (score 15):

Since version 1.3, Clojure comes bundled with the [`clojure.reflect`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/#clojure.reflect) namespace. The function [`reflect`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.reflect-api.html#clojure.reflect/reflect) in particular can be used to show all methods (and other information) for an object. It is not quite as convenient to use as `show`. On the other hand, it is much more general and it is quite easy to write your own version of `show` using `reflect` as a building block.

As an example, if you want to see all methods for String which returns a String:

```
user=> (use 'clojure.reflect)
user=> (use 'clojure.pprint)

user=> (->> (reflect "some object") 
            :members 
            (filter #(= (:return-type %) 'java.lang.String))
            (map #(select-keys % [:name :parameter-types])) 
            print-table)
```

Comment: Does this work with v1.2.1 (if I add a dependency to the project.clj file)?

Answer (score 7):

```
user=> (map #(.getName %) (-> "foo" class .getMethods))

("equals" "toString" "hashCode" "compareTo" "compareTo" "indexOf" "indexOf" "indexOf" "indexOf" "valueOf" "valueOf" "valueOf" "valueOf" "valueOf" "valueOf" "valueOf" "valueOf" "valueOf" "length" "isEmpty" "charAt" "codePointAt" "codePointBefore" "codePointCount" "offsetByCodePoints" "getChars" "getBytes" "getBytes" "getBytes" "getBytes" "contentEquals" "contentEquals" "equalsIgnoreCase" "compareToIgnoreCase" "regionMatches" "regionMatches" "startsWith" "startsWith" "endsWith" "lastIndexOf" "lastIndexOf" "lastIndexOf" "lastIndexOf" "substring" "substring" "subSequence" "concat" "replace" "replace" "matches" "contains" "replaceFirst" "replaceAll" "split" "split" "toLowerCase" "toLowerCase" "toUpperCase" "toUpperCase" "trim" "toCharArray" "format" "format" "copyValueOf" "copyValueOf" "intern" "wait" "wait" "wait" "getClass" "notify" "notifyAll")
```

Replace "foo" with your object.

Comment: Clojure 1.10 adds a new datafy function. It seems to do reflection quite well.

Answer (score 2):

You used to be able to use [show](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.repl-utils/show) for this sort of thing (e.g., with clojure 1.2.0, clojure-contrib 1.2.0).

```
(ns test.core
  (:use [ clojure.contrib.repl-utils :only [show]]))
```

From the REPL

```
(show Integer)
```

yielded

```
===  public final java.lang.Integer  ===
static MAX_VALUE : int 
static MIN_VALUE : int
...
```

Curiously, I tried this with clojure 1.3.0 /clojure-contrib 1.2.0 and it did not work. `doc` seems broken too.

Comment: in 1.2.0 what did you include/use to get this? was it in core?

Comment: @Arthur It was in clojure.contrib.repl-utils. I added the namespace macro above for clarification.

Comment: I did some more digging around. Clojure is migrating away from monolithic clojure.contrib and towards more modular libraries. The doc macro is now in clojure.repl. Not sure if there is a new home for the "show" function. (Too bad, it was useful). Calling repl-utils/show from Clojure 1.3 seems to be broken.

Comment: `clojure.contrib` is depreacted now!

Answer (score 1):

IIRC it's not built-in, but it's also short--[see this implementation](http://travis-whitton.blogspot.com/2009/06/method-introspection.html).

(It might be now.)

Answer (score 1):

You usually do this method listing because you're looking for a particular kind of method..say all the "get" kind of methods in the class.  Here is how you can do that for your object 'obj':

```
(filter #(re-find #"get" %) (map #(.getName %) (.. obj getClass getMethods)))
```

The #"get" is the regular expression object to search for methods that have get in their name (customize it for your own need). The map expression simply produces a seq of all the method names in the object's class; the seq is fed to the anonymous function that is the first parameter passed to filter.